# How to automatically update data in google big query using python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, scheduling

My stages:

- Connect to MySql database using python (IDE:Spyder)
- Pull data and convert dataframe
- Connect to Google Big Query using python
- Write dataframe to Google Big Query

I'm a beginner. Therefore when I want to update the data, I delete the table in the google big query and run the python code again.  Now I want to update the data automatically. Is it possible to do this using python?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Bigquery Python API. You can install it with `pip install google-cloud-bigquery`. Then you can

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Connect to Bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project=your_project_id)

# Pull data to DF
df = client.query('select * from your_dataset.your_table').to_dataframe()

# Write table to Bigquery
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, 'your_dataset.your_table')

# If you want to overwrite an existing table
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
     df, 'your_dataset.your_existing_table', job_config=job_config
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but i still have questions. How can I do this automatically? for example, updating the data in the selected table every day, every week or every month. And 
can i write all these codes via spyder (IDE) or should i use cloud shell.

Comment: Well, you can wrap a similar Python code into a [Cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) and schedule it every day with [Cloud scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler). Or you can use [Cloud composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) to orchestrate the flow. Take a look at the docs, and choose the more viable way for you to productionize the code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution to load data from relation data base to Bigquery is through Apache Beam (as dataflow runner or Local runner) depending on data volume and available infra for data processing.

1. Beam - MYSQL Connector https://pypi.org/project/beam-mysql-connector/
2. Apache Beam Python SDK: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python/
3. Dataflow runner: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow
4. Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crKdfh63-OQ